# How to check if a mongo field with data buffer is empty in an EJS template?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I wanted to know how you could check a MongoDB field to see if an image is stored there. I have the following model file for the mongo schema that is passed into an EJS template using node and express.

```
// schema setup
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    uploadedImage: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: {type: String , default: ""},
    },
    dest: String,
    postdata: String,
    excerpt: String,
    tag: String,
    icon: String,
    color: String,
    featured: String,
    keywords: String,
    description: String,
    create: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
   },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Posts", postSchema);
```

In the following EJS template, I am getting stuck trying to figure out how formulate the if statement to check if there is data in that updoadedImage object. the section of the EJS tempalte affected:

```
<!--REGULAR ROLL-->
      <section>
        <div class="row gx-5">
            <% Posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-4">
            <!-- News block -->
            <div>
              <!-- Featured image -->
              <div class="bg-image shadow-1-strong rounded mb-4" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
<!--THIS IS THE STATEMENT I NEED HELP -->
                <% if (post.uploadedImage.length > 0 ){%>
                <img src="data:image/<%=post.uploadedImage.contentType%>;base64,<%=post.uploadedImage.data.toString('base64')%>" class="img-fluid" />
                <% } else { %>
                <!--IMG URL FAllback -->
                <img src="<%= post.image%>" class="img-fluid animation fade-in slow" />
                <% } %>
                <div class="mask">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-end h-100 p-3">
                    <span class="badge <%= post.color%> me-2"><i class="<%= post.icon%>"></i> <%= post.tag%></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a href="/blog/<%= post._id %>" class="animation fade-in slow">
                  <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15)"></div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <!-- Article title and description -->
              <a href="/blog/<%= post._id %>" class="text-dark animation fade-in">
                <h5 class="fw-bold animation fade-in"><%= post.title %></h5>
              </a>
                <u><%= post.create.toDateString() %></u>
                <p class="card-text mb-3 animation fade-in slow"><%= post.excerpt %></p>
                <a class="btn btn-sm gradient-deep-blue link-light" href="/blog/<%= post._id %>">Read</a>
                <% if(currentUser){ %>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning" href="/blog/<%= post._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
                <% } %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--ENDLOOP-->
          <% }); %>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: You should store only image name in database. Image should be stored somewhere in your public or assets folder. Then while fetching the image, concat the path where the image is stored and the name from database.

Comment: the image that is referenced is actually a URL string that would go in there. The actual uploaded image is a buffer that is uploaded through multer storage.